# page.evaluate returns null document

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

Below is the phantomjs code

```
page.open('https://onli**************uickpay.html', function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network')
    } else {
        console.log('internet is working');
        var ua = page.evaluate(function (loanID) {
            var loanIDSplit = loanID.split('/');
            document.getElementById("txtBranchCode").value = loanIDSplit[0];
            document.getElementById("txtType").value = loanIDSplit[1];
            document.getElementById("txtLoanNumber").value = loanIDSplit[2];
            document.getElementById("btnLoanNoSearch").click();
        }, loanID);

    console.log(util.inspect(document, false, null));
    setTimeout(function () {
        var html = page.evaluate(function () {
            var table = document.getElementById('tblQpLoanNo');
            table.getElementsByClassName('odd')[0].click();
            document.getElementById("LoNoPayButton").click();
            return document;
        });
        page.render('/home/ubuntu/github.png');
        console.log('is the value of document'+html);
    }, 3000);

    setTimeout( function (){
      var release_amount = page.evaluate(function () {
      var table = document.getElementById('tblQpPayment');
      var row = table.getElementsByClassName('odd')[0];
      var payableAmount = row.getElementsByTagName('td')[3].textContent;
      return payableAmount;
  });

     console.log("release amount value is "+release_amount);
     // system.stdout.write("$" + releaseAmount);
     // system.stdout.write("$" + loanID);
     phantom.exit();
}, 10000);
}
```

when the above peace of code runs, **the html value that is logged is showing up null**

It works perfectly with phantomjs in macosx but when I have deployed it to ubuntu server it is not working. I made sure I am using phantomjs that supports linux

The first page.evaluate works fine, where as the next page.evaluate after 3 seconds timeout is not working, I have wasted enough time on debugging and finally asking over here, If some one had same issue or if some information is missing please feel to ask me.

what can be the reasons for document being null, that means there is some problem in evaluating the html page

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return `document` from `page.evaluate` because, according to the [docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html)

> Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will not work!

If you want to get the whole html of the page, try [a built-in](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/content.html) `page.content` variable:

```
console.log(page.content);
```